# How to improve performance of order by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a SQL Server database which contains the tables `Product`, `ProductSpecification` and `ProductRetailer`. To gather all the information I need for my query I run the following

```
SELECT        
    pr.ProductId AS Id, p.Name, p.Category, p.Code, ps.Material, 
    p.Brand, ps.Collection, ps.Colour, ps.SubCollection, ps.SurfaceType, 
    MIN(pr.Price) AS LowestPrice, p.ImageUrl, COUNT(pr.Price) AS DealCount
FROM            
    dbo.ProductRetailer AS pr 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Product AS p ON p.Id = pr.ProductId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.ProductSpecification AS ps ON p.Id = ps.ProductId
GROUP BY 
    pr.ProductId, p.Name, p.Category, p.Code, ps.Material, p.Brand, 
    ps.Collection, ps.Colour, ps.SubCollection, ps.SurfaceType, p.ImageUrl
```

There will be many occasions where I want to order by LowestPrice, however despite only having under 2000 records I find that the query can take up to 45 secs. Is there any way I can improve the speed of this query when using order by?

Execution Plan attached
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy0eWEvN_

SET STATISTICS IO ON OUTPUT

> (1047 rows affected)
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 184, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'ProductRetailer'. Scan count 1064, logical reads 2332, physical reads 7, read-ahead reads 1, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'ProductSpecification'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4998, physical reads 20, read-ahead reads 9, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 368, physical reads 56, read-ahead reads 313, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

Completion time: 2021-03-23T09:17:26.7989169+00:00

Comment: Posting the execution plan, using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) will help us help you. Also having that many columns in the `GROUP BY` has a "code smell"; most likely you should be pre-aggregating before you `JOIN` in a CTE or subquery in an `APPLY`.

Comment: Also: show the **structure** of the table (columns, names and datatypes, and any constraints) and what kind of **indexes** you might have on this table

Comment: I currently have no indexes on the database, I was cautious of indexing columns unnecessarily before checking on here

Comment: I strongly suggest you set the `n/varchar` data type **and size** of the parameter, in order to filter properly. At the moment you have a implicit conversion in your plan

Comment: Under 2000 records in total or _after_ grouping ?

Comment: This is after grouping records

Comment: Your plan does not reflect the query you posted.

Comment: I used a view before, the plan is updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could re-write your query as below to remove the need to group by all your columns and aggregate using an `apply()`

this will likely get you a better execution plan, however without seeing your actual plan and the indexing strategy on your tables it's hard to be sure.

```
select pr.ProductId as Id, p.[Name], p.Category, p.Code, 
    ps.Material, p.Brand, ps.[Collection], 
    ps.Colour, ps.SubCollection, ps.SurfaceType,
    pr.LowestPrice,  p.ImageUrl, pr.DealCount
from dbo.Product as p
join dbo.ProductSpecification as ps on ps.ProductId = p.Id
outer apply (
    select Min(pr.Price) as LowestPrice, Count(pr.Price) as DealCount
    from dbo.ProductRetailer as pr 
    group by pr.ProductId
    where pr.ProductId = p.Id
)pr
```

**Edit**

The answer to your issue is in your execution plan.

The amount of data read by the query is small, only 60 meg. The plan's `sort` operator spills to disk for only a handful of rows, this indicates it didn't receive a high-enough memory grant.

The entire query was only granted 512K, the plan *tells you* the reason why it took so long. The actual query took 4 seconds, see the SSMS output from your plan below.

Your SQL Server is under memory pressure, it waited 25 seconds on that alone. The default minimum granted memory is 1024k yet your query only received 512k. This would suggest someone has been fiddling with settings they do not understand :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I dont have any indexes on the database currently, i had just set it up and started querying, SQL is not my strong point. Should I index the price column to improve this, also where should I use the order by in your query?

Comment: No indexes or also no primary keys / clustered indexes? As suggested above, share your actual execution plan for some suggestions. And index on `price` would definitely be of use.

Comment: I have primary keys on the tables yes, execution plan attached now

Comment: Your execution plan is the estimated, not the actual. Nothing to suggest why it would take so long, the (estimated) rowcounts are small, estimates are a bit out in some cases. Paste the actual plan and also the output from `set statistics io on`

Comment: Sorry didnt realise, updated now with statistics output, include the _ at the end of the url, it doesnt seem to pass in the direct link

Comment: @cg91 Edited above after looking at your actual execution plan.

Comment: Thank you for your time with this @stu, I am no expert by any means and I am glad to have you guys here for some help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating temporary table (which will have result of your inner join) and then do a order by on the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should not be taking 45 seconds on a few thousand records.

The first thing you want are indexes on the columns used in the `join`s:

- `ProductRetailer(productid, price)`
- `ProductSpecification(productid)`

There may be other ways to make the query more efficient, but this is where to start.

Comment: Ok I have indexed like you said and that has brought the query time down to 26 secconds

Comment: @cg91 . . . Are any of the columns really big?  Such as the URL or other columns?

Comment: No Gordon, the url column would not have any more than 70 characters and it is probably the biggest, without the order by clause, the query takes less than 1 sec